# Tables floating right

Tags: outlook, html-table, html-email

I am trying to make my own signature on outlook but seems like tables are floating to right without any reason.

The problem is I only can see the error on outlook, because on my browser, the signature displays well.

How actually it looks like:

[image: Display of outlook]

CODE USED:  You can ignore the p tags since it does not casue the error.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RZ6LR/)

```
<p class=MsoNormal><b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'><span style='font-size:10pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif"; color: #4e4e4e; line-height: 20px;'>Name<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:10pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif"'>Business<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif" ;padding-bottom: 20px;'><a style="color: red; text-decoration: none;" href="mailto:mail@mail.com">Mail</a><o:p></o:p></span></p>
<br>

<table width="498">
<tr>
<td><a href=""><img src="" width="498" height="104" border="0"></a></td>
</tr>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><a href=#><img src="" width="40" height="58" border="0"></a></td>
  <td><a href="#"><img src=""width="30" height="58" border="0"></a></td>
  <td><a href="#"><img src="" width="29" height="58" border="0"></td>
  <td><a href="#"><img src="" width="30" height="58" border="0"></a></td>
  <td><a href=""><img src="" width="28" height="58" border="0"></a></td>
  <td><img src="" width="318" height="58" border="0"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</table>
<tr>
<td><img src="" width="498" height="113" border="0"></td>
</tr>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RZ6LR/)

Answer (score 1):

There are syntax errors in your html code - you're missing closing `</a>` tags, an opening `<table>` tag and have a closing `</table>` tag in the wrong place. This causes rendering problems.

Updated fiddle with correct formatting: http://jsfiddle.net/RZ6LR/2/

Always run your code through the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to catch these layout issues :)